# How do I correctly use sed to search/replace parts of a line from a variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Background: I am using ZenCart php software, with sed I wanted to edit different themes, but with the same php files. So some automatic changes to themes via sed.

```
s1=$'<img itemprop="image" src="'\'' . zen_output_string($src) . '\''"'   
sed -i.bak -r 's/$image = '\''<img src="'\'' \. zen_output_string\($src\) \. '\''" alt="'\'' \. zen_output_string\($alt\) \. '\''"'\'';/'"$s1"/ html_output.php
```

This runs ok, but no changes are in the file, why, what's wrong?

**Edit I managed to workaround this problem, resulting in the following script:**

```
echo "Updating your Zencart theme's files..."
echo "Creating backups of important files."
mkdir -p ./zentmp/includes/functions && cp ./includes/functions/html_output.php ./zentmp/includes/functions/ && mkdir -p ./zentmp/includes/templates && cp -Rf ./includes/templates/ ./zentmp/includes/templates && mkdir -p ./zentmp/includes/classes && cp ./includes/classes/breadcrumb.php /zentmp/includes/classes/
echo "Updating theme file /includes/functions/html_output.php"
s1=$'itemprop="image" src="'\'' . zen_output_string($src) . '\''"'
sed -i -r 's/src="'\'' \. zen_output_string\(\$src\) \. '\''"/'"${s1}"/ html_output.php
echo "File updated..."
s2=$'itemprop="image" class="imgLink"'
for dir in ./zentmp/includes/templates/*/
do
dir=${dir%*/}
echo "Updating theme file /$dir/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php" (1/2)
sed -i -r 's/class="imgLink"/'"${s2}"/ ./$dir/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php
echo "Updating theme file /$dir/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php" (2/2)
s3=$'title="'\'' . addslashes($products_name) . '\'' itemprop="image"'
sed -i -r 's/title="'\'' \. addslashes\(\$products\_name\) \. '\''"/'"${s3}"/ ./$dir/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php
done
```

The above works pretty well, until the following piece of code:

```
for dir2 in ./zentmp/includes/templates/*/
do
dir2=${dir2%*/}
s4=$"<span itemprop="name"><?php echo \$products_name; ?>"
sed -i -r 's/<?php echo \$products_name; ?>'/'"${s4}"/ ./$dir2/tpl_product_info_display.php
done
```

As requested, I'll post the snippets I'm trying to replace in order of usage:

> ```
> $image = '<img src="' . zen_output_string($src) . '" alt="' . zen_output_string($alt) . '"';
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> $image = '<img itemprop="image" src="' . zen_output_string($src) . '" alt="' . zen_output_string($alt) . '"';
> ```

Second:

> ```
> <span class="imgLink">
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> <span  itemprop="image" class="imgLink">
> ```

Third:

```
$rel . '" title="' . addslashes($products_name) . '">
```

to

```
$rel . '" title="' . addslashes($products_name) . '" itemprop="image">
```

Note that the 2nd sed is used twice.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Final code should look like: $image = '<img itemprop="image" src="' . zen_output_string($src) . '" alt="' . zen_output_string($alt) . '"';

Comment: variables inside single quotes aren't expanded.

Comment: Please post an example of the actual code the substitute should succeed on. I think it would be easier to build a regex to see where you've gone wrong, than deconstruct the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r -i.bak --posix "/$image = '<img src=/ s/<img src=/<img itemprop=\"image\" src=/
/<span class=/ s/class=/itemprop=\"image\" class=/
/\\$rel.*title.*addslashes/ s/> *$/ itemprop=\"image\">/
" sample.txt
```

3 section, eache searching and limited line with expected pattern, than replace just part needed inside (avoiding lot of " and ' conversion by shell)

\" arround image are mandatory for simplification (could use a back pattern like \1 if capture of the " are made in search patterne of s/
\$ is necessary on the last searche due to shell and sed substitution

--posix is there to allow reuse of the same sed code in non GNU sed